# Linux file attributes of /

Tags: linux, attributes, program-entry-point, drive, partition

I'm having some issues listing the file attributes of the main '/' partition, namely to see if it is immutable. Running a simple 'lsattr /' shows all directories under it, excluding the directory itself.

Is there some hack with '--' or just an alternate command that can check this? It doesn't help that searching special characters is quite difficult on Google.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux the "`.`" refers to current directory.
You can see the lsattr for "/" by supplying the `-a` option.

```
lsattr -a /


-------------e-- /.
```